# When text select, selection is over the div size, not within div

Tags: html, css

first, sorry for my english skill.

btw, drag some text(text-selection) is over div.
i want remove useless selection

in my case :
[image: http://i.imgur.com/WqgCNvm.png]

how to fix it?

my blog link : devflow.kr

Comment: please show your code

Comment: You are probably using Chrome and you can't change that behaviour, this on of the reasons I don't like Chrome.

Comment: @NabilKadimi thanks for comment. is it chorme problems?.. okay.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow:hidden;` to the parent div.